# Customize WooCommerce my account dashboard through plugin

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am making a plugin that adds some functionality to woocommerce. I dislike the bland default woocommerce "my account dashboard" page and I would like to change the way the dashboard looks. I have been looking online and it seems the only way to do this would be to modify the theme or the template inside of woocommerce plugin itself.

I want to make my plugin as portable as possible therefore, I would like for my plugin to modify the my account dashboard page, and not the PHP code of the template or the woocommerce plugin. Is there a way to do this as a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it in what I would consider a sloppy way. On the `init` hook I check the WooCommerce template against my custom template and if the WooCommerce template does not match my template then I replace the WooCommerce template with my template.

```
add_action( 'init', 'run_inital' );
function run_inital(){
    $wooThemePath = $woocommerce->plugin_path()."/templates/myaccount/dashboard.php";
    $myThemeFile = file_get_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."/WooCommerce/dashboard.php");
    $WooThemeFile = file_get_contents($wooThemePath);
    if($myThemeFile != $WooThemeFile){
        $Woo_Theme = fopen($wooThemePath, "w");
        fwrite($Woo_Theme, $myThemeFile);
    }

}
```

If you wanted to make this snippet better you should check to see if the file sizes are different instead of comparing the contents.